# Conversion of a date timestamp column in pandas to a correct format

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a column that is in the following format:

```
01JAN2014:08:22:00
01JAN2014:09:01:00
01JAN2014:10:00:00
01JAN2014:10:32:00
```

Tableau cannot read this because I think its in the wrong date format. I have tried converting it in tableau but it still doesn't work. So I was thinking of recreating the column by parsing out the month, day, year, and timestamp. Then joining the columns into `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format which Tableau and other things can read.

I tried running this in python

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.read_csv(filelocation)['ENTERED_TIME']
from datetime import datetime
for date in dates:
    d = datetime.strptime(date,'%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

But it doesn't work because it says the following:

```
time data '01JAN2014:08:22:00' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: Could you give us your _real_ code, as the code you've posted will clearly not give that error.

Comment: You need to take out the hyphens and make %m into %b, as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Even though you edited your code, my comment is still the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the date column while reading the input file:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

series = pd.read_csv(filelocation, parse_dates=['ENTERED_TIME'],
    date_parser=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"))
```

See [read_csv() docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: d = "01JAN2014:08:22:00"

In [3]: d_ = datetime.strptime(d, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")

In [4]: d_
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 8, 22)
```

In `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

s = ["01JAN2014:08:22:00",
     "01JAN2014:09:01:00",
     "01JAN2014:10:00:00",
     "01JAN2014:10:32:00"]

s_ = pd.Series(s)

print s_.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,"%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"))
```

Output in `pandas`:

```
0   2014-01-01 08:22:00
1   2014-01-01 09:01:00
2   2014-01-01 10:00:00
3   2014-01-01 10:32:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. Is there a way to optimize this? I am trying to run through 1,700,000 rows.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question. On my end, I tested it against one million rows and returned 17.9s. Unless you're doing this en masse, a little above or double that doesn't seem so bad for 1.7 million.